# save filename and information from the file into a two column txt doc. ubuntu terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

I have a question regarding the manipulation and creation of text files in the ubuntu terminal. I have a directory that contains several 1000 subdirectories. In each directory, there is a file with the extension stats.txt. I want to write a piece of code that will run from the parent directory, and create a file with the name of all the stats.txt files in the first column, and then returns to me all the information from the 5th line of the same stats.txt file in the next column. The 5th line of the stats.txt file is a sentence of six words, not a single value.

For reference, I have successfully used the sed command in combination with find and cat to make a file containing the 5th line from each stats.txt file. I then used the ls command to save a list of all my subdirectories. I assumed both files would be in alphabetical order of the subdirectories, and thus easy to merge, but I was wrong. The find and cat functions, or at least my implementation of them, resulted in a file that appeared to be random in order (see below). No need to try to remedy this code, I'm open to all solutions.

```
# loop through subdirectories and save the 5th line of stats.txt as a different file.
for f in ~/*; do [ -d $f ] && cd "$f" && sed -n 5p *stats.txt > final.stats.txt done;

# find the final.stats.txt files and save them as a single file
find ./ -name 'final.stats.txt' -exec cat {} \; > compiled.stats.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this can help you get on track:

```
find . -name "*stats.txt" -exec awk 'FNR==5{print FILENAME, $0}' '{}' + > compiled.stats
```

Comment: THANK YOU.  This solution works well. It does, however, save the full file path in addition to the file name. This will work for my purposes though, and I can optimize further if necessary.